# Начало карьеры программиста

Tags: работа

С чего по вашему мнению стоит начинать карьеру? Устроиться в небольшую студию и набираться опыта там или начать с фриланса? если фриланс, то подскажите пожалуйста сайты, где зарегистрированы вы, или просто хорошие сайты.

Comment: А какой у вас профиль программиста? Какие языки программирования знаете?
Для фриланса смотреть следующие сайты:
http://freelancer.ru/
https://www.free-lance.ru/
http://24freelance.net/

Comment: Научиться пользоваться поиском, если надо сайты фрилансеров найти )) А вообще, любое обучение начинается с прочтения хорошей специализированной литературы.

Comment: языки программирования - php,mysql,js,java, профиль соответственно web-программист

Comment: сайты фрилансеров я нашел) вопрос был, на каких сайтах зарегистрированы ВЫ.

Comment: oDesk, elance

Comment: то есть вы, якобы зная php, js и mysql, хотите фрилансом заработать на кусок хлеба? Чтож удачи...может, именно что на кусок хлеба  и заработаете

Comment: ну не якобы, а html и css я не указал потому, что это языки разметки, а не программирования. и вообще - читайте впрос

Comment: Про html и css я ничего и не говорил. Почему якобы? Да хотя бы потому что у вас нет опыта работы, что уже говорит о том, что хорошим программистом вы вряд ли являетесь, что бы вы там себе ни думали. Плюс к тому занимаетесь вы php и js - самыми простыми (с некоторыми оговорками) языками программирования, которые способна выучить любая обезьяна (это я сейчас не в ваш адрес)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смотря какую именно карьеру вы желаете поиметь. Если жениться/выйти замуж - то однозначно направляйтесь в большую компанию. В большой компании, к счастью/сожалению, вы будете винтиком в большой машине.  Из вас будут вытягивать душу, но взамен вы получаете обеспеченность. Ваши личные устремления, в некоторой степени, будут проигнорированы и мало кого заинтересуют.  Но друзей будет очень много. Профессионализм у вас будет узкоспециализированный.

Можно устроиться и в небольшую компанию. Средства к существованию будут, а в дополнение вам будет доступно понимание организационных моментов, сложностей, тонкостей и нюансов предпринимательства. Набравшись некоторого опыта, в особенности управленческого, если останется желание, вы можете организовать своё дело.

Не забываем и про фриланс. Фрилансеры, и особенно начинающие, как правило, не особо загружены работой. Раз в три месяца им поступает предложение на участие в тендере, где нужно ещё убедить клиента в высшей степени своего мастерства, в отличие от сотоварищей. Тут и там встречаются замечания от текущих фрилансеров, про работу предыдущих фрилансеров, что не очень качественно сказывается на уровне ответственности последних. Вкупе ко всему этому, вы набьёте своих шишек, натрёте свои мозоли. Но, если получится, выйдете прожжённым победителем IT сферы.

Comment: очень информативно)

Answer (score 0):

Карьера только с php и js? Очень сомнительно. Если действительно хотите интересную и стабильную профессиональную жизнь, освойте что-то вроде питона, руби и/или джавы. Эти языки и технологии требуются в действительно серьезных и интересных проектах.

Comment: вообще-то я написал, что знаю java

Comment: Тогда лучше обратите внимание на jee и подобные вещи.

Comment: а asp.net?

Comment: Тоже можно.

Comment: Вообще без хорошего порфолио во фриланс можно не соваться.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше идти в большую компанию, потому что:

- там, как правило, есть программы обучения/развития новичков и внятное разделение на junior/middle/senior
- четкое разделение ролей в команде и более-менее правильный процесс разработки (тестирование, agile и т.д.)
- больше людей -- больше знакомств, которые, если что, пригодятся позже